# Show output from child scripts in the parent console window

Tags: vbscript, stdout

I'm calling VBScripts from inside of a VBScript and I want their console output to appear in the window from which I'm calling them. So when I have this code

```
WScript.Stdout.WriteLine( "Checking out unit tests" )

ObjWshShell.Run "%comspec% \c checkoutUnitTests.vbs", 0, True
```

the the only output I see is

```
Checking out unit tests
```

when I want to see all the output from `checkoutUnitTests.vbs` concatenated onto that output in the same window. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to use .Exec and .Stdout.Readline() as in this bare bone demo script:

mother.vbs

```
Option Explicit

Dim oWS : Set oWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo "A", "mother starts child"
Dim oEx : Set oEx = oWS.Exec("cscript child.vbs")
Do Until oEx.Stdout.AtEndOfStream
   WScript.Echo oEx.Stdout.ReadLine()
Loop
WScript.Echo "B", "mother done"
```

child.vbs:

```
Option Explicit

Dim n
For n = 1 To 5
    WScript.Echo n, "child"
Next
```

output:

```
cscript mother.vbs
A mother starts child
1 child
2 child
3 child
4 child
5 child
B mother done
```

Added:

see [Pythonic version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17305761/603855)

Comment: doesn't work for me, opens a new window & all output is in that new window.

Comment: I ran `cscript mother.vbs` in console, which in turn runs `cscript child.vbs`, this `child.vbs` opens a new cmd. A new thing here is that `child.vbs` expects user-input.

Comment: Ask a new question (perhaps referencing to this answer); publish (the important parts of) your child.vbs.