# Retrieving the command output of a hidden console?

Tags: python, command-line, vbscript, dos, stdout

I run a DOS command from a python environment which retrieves its command output via stdout.

All is working fine excepted that the windows console pops out everytime the script runs, so I need a way to hide the windows console.

Schematically, here is the expected process:

```
"Console1" runs "hidden Console2" and retrieves its output into "Console1"
```

I read some recommendations with softwares like "*HiddenStart*" or "*chp*" which hide the console when executing DOS commands and batch scripts. Another solution in VBScript can also achieve this result with the following code:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c COMMAND GOES HERE"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

But unfortunately, neither "*HiddenStart*" nor "*chp*" nor the VBScript script allow to retrieve the command output of the executed commands. "*Chp*" outputs a stdout but only for the exit process code.

Some might say that one could log the result to a file on disk, and then retrieve the content of the file, but it is not what needed and results in a more complicated process.

So, I'm wondering if it is at all possible to retrieve the command output from a hidden console, is it?

SOLUTION:

[How to avoid console window with .pyw file containing os.system call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765078/how-to-avoid-console-window-with-pyw-file-containing-os-system-call/12964900#12964900)

NOTE OF THE AUTHOR OF THE POST:
*Hi, this is my first time here, and this question is not a duplicate but a variant. Proof to that is that i made a search before and it was difficult to find the solution before I actually wrote the question. So, moderators need to be a bit more subtle than that. This is a linked, related question or a variant, but not a duplicate, I think. Thanks.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025179/python-calling-external-programs-without-opening-console-dos-prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A windows-centric solution could be based on a 'port' from [this VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17302770/603855):

mother.py:

```
import win32com.client
oWS = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
print("A", "mother starts child")
oEx = oWS.Exec("cscript ..\\vbs\\child.vbs")
while not oEx.Stdout.AtEndOfStream:
   print(oEx.Stdout.ReadLine())
print("B", "mother done")
```

output:

```
A mother starts child
1 child
2 child
3 child
4 child
5 child
B mother done
```

(ActiveState Python 3.2.2; removing the () from the `print`s gives a 2.x version (tested with ActiveState Python 2.5.2); to use intrinsics like `dir`, prepend "%comspec% /c ")

Comment: Thanks Ekkehard. Just to note that i'm using a python environment but with no easy access to third-party modules like pywin32. So, as I pointed out at the end of the first post, a solution is to flag "Shell=True" the subprocess method, and it worked as expected from the first requirement.

Comment: The flag solution only works with python, that said. From a windows DOS command the question remains opened.

Answer (score 0):

Try subprocess pipe examples for ways to do exactly this.

Comment: Thanks, could you be more explicit ? Here the code I'm using inside the python script: process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

Comment: It is true but the comment is not an answer. Thanks anyway Mr Barnes.